# Changes made in Javascript files not reflected in the browser. FTP. Ubuntu Server

Tags: javascript, caching, ubuntu, ftp

I am editing files through FTP connection. The changes are not reflecting on the browsers. I have followed instructions of using key combinations such as **Ctrl** and **F5** keys, to clear cache but for some reason nothing is happening. So the server runs on an Ubuntu. I am using an FTP connection to edit and view the files. Do I need to do something server-side to clear or turn the development mode on? Considering I have an access to the server. I have been googling and on 10-hour coding but I could not get this one to work. It's my firs time to have an access, too, if that should help.

Comment: What browser are you using? And on what local machine? Have you considered turning off caching in your headers? http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the server.Also ensure that the changes that you are doing are reflecting when you reopens the file using FTP connection.

Comment: Hi. Yes, the changes are there. I have to close and re-open the file to make sure the changes are saved.

Comment: Now check by restarting the server and use ctrl + alt + delete for deleting the browser history.